# While updating DropDownList the selected value is not picked properly; instead random value is returned

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
protected void wbsDropDown_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //txtWBSDesc.Text = wbsDropDown.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
    //txtWBSDesc.Text = wbsDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();   
    txtWBSDesc.Text = this.wbsDropDown.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
}
```

The value of some DropDownList items are returned properly always. Wrong values from the List is returned randomly.
Here Aspx
this is aspx below

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="ms-long">
    <tr>
        <td  style="padding-right:2px;" class="ms-formbody">
            <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="wbsDropDown" width="115px" CssClass="text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="wbsDropDown_Change" />
        </td>
        <td align="left">
            <asp:Label ID="lblWBSNoName" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtWBSDesc" width="350px" runat="server" class="ms-textfield ms-long ms-readonly"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here Binding the Data

```
//update WBS dropdown by ram
                DataTable dtWBS = MMHE.iPS.Lib.AcctCostCentre.GetWBS_DT(txtJobNo.Text.ToString());
                wbsDropDown.DataSource = dtWBS;
                wbsDropDown.DataTextField = "WBSElement";
                wbsDropDown.DataValueField = "Descrip";
                wbsDropDown.DataBind();
                wbsDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JobNo.eWBSElement.ToString()))
                {
                    wbsDropDown.SelectedItem.Text = JobNo.eWBSElement.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    wbsDropDown.SelectedItem.Text = JobNo.eClaim_WBSElement.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: Are you binding values to DropDown from DB? Also could you please post the code binding text to DropDown? Is it in PageLoad()?

Comment: Yes am binding values to DB. its not in PageLoad.

Comment: Then how is it. I am asking just to make sure, the DropDown is not rebound with each postback.

Comment: after selecting the element the control come here to show the value and then it will be saved in DB..

Comment: Where is the code that binds values to the DropDownList? In the ASP.NET code you posted it declares the DropDownList and in CodeBehind cs, the value is being accessed. Where is the value binding code?

Comment: In the ASP.NET Page Life Cycle where is the binding code called? Like in PageLoad() or Button Click etc.?

Comment: the binding code is being called in PageLoad

Comment: If you call it in PageLoad(), then make sure the binding code is not called on each postback. Instead check for IsPostBack property before binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the way you set the Selected Item of DropDown.

Instead of:
wbsDropDown.SelectedItem.Text = JobNo.eWBSElement.ToString();

Use the below method after binding and inserting the Default entry ("--Select--").

You will need to set the selection based on Value.

```
wbsDropDown.ClearSelection(); //making sure the any preselection has been cleared
wbsDropDown.Items.FindByValue(value).Selected = true;
```

**Note:** Also, if you have the bind code in PageLoad(), make sure the binding code is not called on each postback. Instead check for IsPostBack property before binding.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i end up with this solution..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function WBSDropDown(ddl) 
  {
     document.getElementById('<%=txtWBSDesc.ClientID %>').value = ddl.value;
  }
  </script>

<asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="false" onchange="WBSDropDown(this);" runat="server" ID="wbsDropDown" width="115px" CssClass="text" OnSelectedIndexChanged="wbsDropDown_Change" />
```